# Where to install a program?

Tags: home-directory, binary

I want to download and run this,

http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html

But I'm not 100% sure where to run it from. I've downloaded it to my DOWNLOADS folder in my home directly but I've heard that it's bad form to run things from your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping source code and downloaded programs right in your `/home` folder can get a little messy and disorganized. Saving them to your `~/Downloads` folder or any other subdirectory is fine, but you have to be careful not to delete them, for example, if you go on a deleting rampage in your `~/Downloads` folder to get rid of accumulated junk. As a solution to this, I have created a `~/Projects` subdirectory, wherein I have individual folders for each software project, source code bundle, or other "project". If you don't have many Projects to keep track of, keeping them in your Downloads folder (or any folder) is fine if you don't mind the extra eyeload of having it there.

To run `btsync`, download the .tar.gz folder, and then open your Downloads folder in Nautilus (the file manager). Then right click the .tar.gz file and select "Extract Here". Once done extracting, open a terminal and run the command:

```
~/Downloads/btsync_i386/btsync
```

And btsync will run.

Cheers!